# Optimize lower triangle matrix transpose

Tags: c, optimization

I have to optimize the following function so it runs faster: Note(this is a lower triangle transpose)

```
void trans(int ** source, int** destination)
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < sizee ; i ++) 
    { 
        for (int j = i +1 ; j < sizee ; j ++) 
        {
            destination[i][j]= source[j][i];
        } 
    }
}
```

I understand that the accesses to source don't have spatial locality because it is being accessed by columns, but I don't understand how I would implement this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: I tried tiling, although the runtime improved, the optimized transpose is producing the wrong result:

```
#define b 2
for (int ii = 0 ; ii < sizee ; ii += b) { 
    for (int jj = ii +1 ; jj < sizee ; jj +=b) {
        for(int i = ii; i < std::min(ii+b-1, sizee); i++)
        {
            for(int j = jj; j < std::min(jj+b-1, sizee); j++)
            {
        destination[i][j]= source[j][i];
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Your inner loop needs looks wrong - I think it needs to be: `for (int j = 0; j < sizee; j++)` - you may be getting mixed up between in-place and not-in-place transpose algorithms.

Comment: Does sizee vary?  if it is a fixed value, or only fluctuates between a couple values, it opens up some optimization opportunities.

Comment: We're assuming the matrix is lower triangle, so we're only interested in the elements below the diagonal, that's why j starts at i+1

Comment: sizee is constant, it is 100.

Comment: If you only want a lower triangular transpose then please state that in the question so that people don't waste time providing answers which are not appropriate for your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing a cache-friendly transpose algorithm is to tile the data:

```
- for each square tile
    - load a square tile from source into a temporary buffer
    - transpose tile in-place
    - write out transpose tile to its correct location in dest
```

Choose the tile size so that it fits comfortably within cache.

For further optimisation you can work on the in-place tile transpose routine - there are plenty of micro-optimisations you can do on e.g. an 8x8 or 16x16 in-place transpose.

---

*Note: this answer was provided for the original version of the question when it was not apparent that the requirement was for a partial transpose. I'm leaving the answer here though as it has some useful comments below.*

Comment: Hmm. I read up on tiling, and tried something like this, although the runtime is faster, the result of my optimized transpose is wrong. I edited the post to add the optimized version.

Comment: @SKLAK Note that with tiling, not only do you have to transpose each tile, but the off-diagonal tiles need to be swapped to a different location. Your code posted above does not appear to address that fact.

Comment: @twalberg: The question as presented shows a source array and a destination array, suggesting an out-of-place transpose. It is possible `source` and `destination` might point to the same array, and that would be a separate problem.

Comment: Which tiles are you referring to by "off-diagonal"? The tiles that run down the diagonal of the matrix?

Comment: @SKLAK No, the tiles that *don't* contain the diagonal elements. I.e. the top right tile not only needs to be transposed, but it needs to be swapped with the bottom left tile in the result, not just merely transposed in place.

Comment: Since we are only transposing the bottom triangle, we wouldn't need swap any blocks right?

Comment: @SKLAK Yes you would still need to swap blocks - the transpose of a lower triangular matrix should be an upper triangular matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by inverting your loop.  Put `j` on the outside and `i` on the inside.  Here's why: the following locations are all right next to each other in memory:

```
source[j][0];
source[j][1];
source[j][2];
source[j][3];
```

But these locations are not:

```
source[0][i];
source[1][i];
source[2][i];
source[3][i];
```

The moment the CPU finishes reading `source[j][0]` into a register, you have an entire cache line of data in your L1 cache.  Take advantage of that by having your reads progress linearly over the address space instead of being scattered.

You can also [unroll your loops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unwinding).  The CPU likes it when you can execute lots of instructions with no branching.

```
    for (int j = i +1 ; j < sizee ; j += 8) 
    {
        destination[i][j]= source[j][i];
        destination[i][j+1]= source[j+1][i];
        destination[i][j+2]= source[j+2][i];
        destination[i][j+3]= source[j+3][i];
        destination[i][j+4]= source[j+4][i];
        destination[i][j+5]= source[j+5][i];
        destination[i][j+6]= source[j+6][i];
        destination[i][j+7]= source[j+7][i];
    }
```

If your CPU has prefetching instructions then you can ask it to start loading the next row of data before you have finished with the current block of memory.

Comment: Swapping the indices to make the source consecutive makes the destination strided, and that is typically worse because partial writes of destination cache lines force the cache lines to be both read and written, while partial reads of source cache lines are merely read. Generally, one should read and write in tiles that are large enough in each dimension that they span full cache lines in both the source and the destination. At that point, the order of individual element access may be more a matter of convenience to the rest of the algorithm than of cache effects.